# Trying to understand quotient ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

From my understanding of the definition:

$(G/U,+,\cdot)$ is quotient ring, where the set $G/U=\{a + U \mid a \in G\}\stackrel{?}{=}\{a+b \mid a \in G, b \in U\}$.

For example:
$$\mathbb{Z}=\{\dots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots\}$$
$$6\mathbb{Z}=\{\dots,-18,-12,-6,0,6,12,18,\dots\}$$

Therefore:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}&=\{a+6\mathbb{Z} \mid a \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
&=\{\dots,-3+6\mathbb{Z},-2+6\mathbb{Z},-1+6\mathbb{Z},6\mathbb{Z},1+6\mathbb{Z},2+6\mathbb{Z},\dots\}\\
&=\{\dots,-3-12,-3-6,-3,-3+6,-3+12,\dots,2-6,2,2+6,2+12,\dots\}\\
&=\{\dots,-15,-9,-3,3,9,\dots,-4,2,8,14,\dots\}
\end{align*}

However, the set $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ should be equal to the set $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, which obviously isn't. Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: The $\overset{?}{=}$ equality is wrong. The $a+U$ are *sets*, and $G/U$ is the set of these sets, not their union.

Comment: The elements of ${Z}_6$ are equivalent classes.

Comment: Then what is the correct equality? I took the equality from my handouts, where is written: $\overline{a}=a+m \cdot \mathbb{Z} = \{a+k \cdot m \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. From this I guess $a+6\mathbb{Z}=\{a+k \mid k \in 6\mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: If I understand your question, this one is correct, and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of equivalent classes : $\overline{0}$,...,$\overline{m-1}$

Comment: Ok, I think I start to get it. So basically, $G/U=\{\{a+b \mid b \in U\} \mid a \in G\}$, am I right? But by this definition $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is infinitely large set of infinitely large sets, isn't it?

Comment: @dash It is a _finite_ set of infinitely large sets, because, for example, $1+6\mathbb{Z}=7+6\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @dash: Yes, $G/U = \left\{\left\{a+b\mid b\in U\right\} \mid a \in G\right\}$. But no, $\mathbb{Z} / 6\mathbb{Z}$ is not infinitely large, because many of these $\left\{a+b \mid b\in U\right\}$'s are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} = \{\bar0,\bar1,\bar2,\ldots,\bar 5\} = \{6\mathbb{Z},\; 1+6\mathbb{Z},\; 2+6\mathbb{Z},\;\ldots,\;5+6\mathbb{Z}\}$

or if you prefer

$=\{\{\ldots,-12,-6,0,6,12,18,\ldots\},\{\ldots,-11,-5,1,7,13,\ldots\},\ldots,\{\ldots,-1,5,11,\ldots\}\}$

You cannot just collapse the layers of brackets.  $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is a set with six elements; each of these elements is a set with an infinite number of elements (one equivalence class for the congruence-mod-6 equivalence relation).  In your question, the equal sign with a "$?$" on top is wrong, and in the last chain of equalities, the third (penultimate) one is wrong.

Of course, $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ also contains $\bar 6 = 6+6\mathbb{Z}$, but this is the same as $\bar 0 = 6\mathbb{Z}$, and similarly $\bar 7=\bar 1$ and so on (that's the reason for taking the quotient in the first place).  There are just six different elements.

Comment: Thank you, this is much more understandable than my handouts. But then set of integers $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0,1,\dots,5\}$ is not equal to power set $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=\{\overline{0},\overline{1},\dots,\overline{5}\}$, but there is just isomorphism between these two sets?

Comment: Yes, they are different, although *if we put the right addition and multiplication* on $\{0,\ldots,5\}$ (namely "operate and then reduce mod 6"), then they are indeed isomorphic, which is why one tends to consider them as identical (what matters is structure, not identity), as bars are tedious to write. (Also, I assume "power set" in what your comment is not what you meant to say, because it makes no sense at this place.)

Answer (score 0):

Remember, whenever you divide you are forming "equivalence relations". That is: if I had 12 squares of chocolate to be divided between 3 people, I would number them and assign the 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th to Pete's box; the 2nd, 5th, 8th, 11th to Bob's; and the 3rd, 6th, 9th, 12th to Bill's. 
I am declaring two squares "equivalent" (belonging to the same person) if their difference is a multiple of three, thus I end up with 3 "equivalence classes" (the resulting boxes).

Now, if I had infinitely many balls to be divided between 6 people, again I would form equivalence classes. I would number them and then colour the ..., -11th, -5th, 1st, 7th, 13th,... blue; the ...,-10th, -4th, 2nd, 8th, 14th, red; etc. so that the infinite number of balls come in 6 colours, each assigned to one person. I am declaring two balls "equivalent" if their difference is a multiple of 6.

$a \sim b \hskip5pt iff \hskip5pt a-b \in 6\mathbb{Z}$

As a result, I end up with 6 equivalence classes, each consisting of infinitely manny balls. So you see how $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ has only 6 elements, where each of these elements is an infinite set (equivalence class), consisting of all the numbers whose difference lies in $6\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand this. My source of confusion was probably the statement on Mathworld, where is written $\mathbb{Z}_6=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, so I tried to somehow generate a set of six integers. I think it should be more highlighted that it is actually only $\mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: OK, apologies if I seemed patronising but I remember being similarly confused about the coset definition and it took so long before it finally clicked for me how natural quotient spaces are when though of as equivalence relations I can't help but want to share my childish analogies! For me there is just no difference between $\mathbb{Z}_6=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6\simeq \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and this only really became apparent once I had understood why the quotient space is so natural.